# React Native: How to use KeyboardAwareScrollView programatic scroll to any TextInput

Tags: react-native

I would like to use scroll to TextInput component programatically how it is described in here: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view. However I get an error

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollToFocusedInput' of undefined, js engine: hermes

The this.scroll is getting found, but this.scroll.props returns undefined. I have placed the function

```
 const _scrollToInput = (reactNode) => {...};
```

before the render method. Then inside the render method I return KeyBoardAwareScrollView with

```
innerRef={(ref) => { this.scroll = ref; }}
```

Inside KeyBoardAwareScrollView I have custom component CredentialsInput to which I pass _scrollToInput and then inside CredentialsInput it's called in onFocus of TextInput as

```
onFocus={(event) => {
            _scrollToInput(ReactNative.findNodeHandle(event.target));
          }}
```

I have followed this guidelines:

> **Programatically scroll to any TextInput**
>
> In order to scroll to any TextInput field, you can use the built-in method scrollToFocusedInput.
> Example:

```
_scrollToInput (reactNode: any) {
  // Add a 'scroll' ref to your ScrollView
  this.scroll.props.scrollToFocusedInput(reactNode)
}

<KeyboardAwareScrollView
  innerRef={ref => {
    this.scroll = ref
  }}>
  <View>
    <TextInput
      onFocus={(event: Event) => {
        // `bind` the function if you're using ES6 classes
        this._scrollToInput(ReactNative.findNodeHandle(event.target))
      }}
    />
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Could somebody please provide complete minimal example that I can run in a new project and not a code-snippet as in the explanation provided by the author of the library? If I just copy the explanation to empty project it does not run, as it complains about types ( which is easy to fix ) and about _scrollToInput, which has to be a variable pointing to a function or an actual function.